# The "x-auth-token" header in Router.all() returns undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, jwt

I am currently building an application using React for frontend and Nodejs for backend powered by Express.js.
I'm using jsonwebtoken for security method and applying a middleware called `auth.js` to authorize the request on every endpoints that starts with `/rest`, here is the code for `auth.js`:

```
const token = req.header('x-auth-token');
console.log(token); // Get the token from 'x-auth-token' header
if (!token) {
    return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Authorization denied. ' });
}

try {
    // validate the token
    next();
} catch (e) {

    return res.status(401).json({ msg: 'Invalid token. '})
}
```

and the routing for `/rest/*` endpoints:

```
router.all("/", auth, (req, res) => {
    // some codes
});
```

the request:

```
fetch(url + "/rest", {
    method: "GET",
    mode: "cors",
    headers: {
        "x-auth-token" : "this is the token" // define the header 
        "Accept" : "application/json",
        "Content-Type" : "application/json",
    }
});
```

The `router.all()` mechanism works fine, I'm able to access every `/res` routes with all methods. The problem is, the value of the `x-auth-token` header in the `auth.js` middleware always gives "undefined". when I change the routing to `route.get()` or `route.post()` etc.., that value of the `x-auth-token` returns the token from client correctly.

Am I missing something with the work around this `router.all()`? Thank you all.

---

EDIT: here's my cors middleware

```
module.exports = cors = (req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', {domain});
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type , Accept, x-auth-token');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
}
```

---

SOLVED:
So turns out, the reason why my `x-auth-token` header is missing in the `req` is because of the [Pre-flight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) mentioned by @Marcos Casagrande.
Now, what I went with is installing the [CORS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) package and configured it following the [Express documents](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html) and ended up with the following snippet in the `server.js` file since I want that `cors` configuration to be applied on every endpoints:

```
let cors = require("cors");
let whitelist = [{domains}]
let corsOptions = {
    origin: (origin, callback) => {
        if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1 || !origin) {
            callback(null, true)
        } else {
            callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
        }
    }
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Thank you all for helping me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `router.all`, `OPTIONS` will need to be handled, and `x-auth-token` won't be available there.
When you issue a request from the browser, an `OPTIONS` request will be issued first by the browser.

If you put:

```
console.log(req.method, req.headers);
```

You'll see: `OPTIONS` & `x-auth-token` missing. After `OPTIONS` has been handled correctly, the browser will issue the `GET` request, where the header will be present.

So you can handle it your self, and set the right `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header if issuing a CORS request, or use `cors` package.

```
const app = require('express')();
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors());

// ...

router.all("/", auth, (req, res) => {
    // No OPTIONS here, was already handled by `cors`
});
```

If you're not issuing a CORS request just use this in your `auth` middleware:

```
if(req.method === 'OPTIONS')
    return res.send(); // 200
```

or handle options first

```
router.options('*', (req, res) => res.send());

router.all("/", auth, (req, res) => {
    // some codes
});
```

Read more about [Preflight Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request)

Comment: I'm a bit lost here, so is what I have to do now is handle the OPTION method by blocking it in the cors?

Comment: No, you're not blocking it. You're responding correctly to `OPTION` request using `cors` middleware.

Comment: Try the code, and you will se it's working. Read about: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request

Comment: I've read the article and checked my `cors` middleware, the code to apply that `cors` file is `app.use(cors)`. Could you check the updated question please?

Answer (score 0):

I see you are trying to access header value from `req.header` and not from `req.headers`, and you have a `"Content-Type" : "application/json",` in you `GET` request which will make a `OPTION` request anyway.

Your client app is making a cross origin request and you nodejs server must handle it. You can use the [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) to solve this.

You can send token in any custom header, but a better practice/standardisation is to use `Authorization` header.

Comment: Sorry for my shallow minded head, but I've actually tried to use req.headers() and got a "req.headers() is not a function". Must have been something wrong with my syntax, I guess?